# Do you need to break after you return false

Tags: c++, return, switch-statement, break

In a switch statement inside a bool function I have this.  Do I add break or is it implied I am very bad at this.

```
case Stop:
default:
    return false;
//break;??????
```

Comment: Since the `default` is normally the last case in the switch, the `break` becomes doubly redundant. It's unreachable because of the return, and in any case a `break` as the last thing in a `switch` just jumps to the same place that you'd "fall out" to anyway, the first statement after the end of the `switch`. But regardless of whether it does anything, some style guides want every `case` to have either a `break` or at least a comment saying something like "fall through", just because people find it very easy to forget the `break` when it is needed.

Comment: @SteveJessop, of course `default` does not need to be last in the switch statement. And since many people, for whatever reason, simply add new `case` statements to the end of the `switch`, it seems a good preventative measure to not let the final case/default fall-through to the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No if you return from `default` case break statement isn't necessary there.

You must add break statement only after all your cases which you want to operate and stop switch's work, otherwise default is operated returning from function.

Comment: I would refine this to "if you return from any case".

Answer (score 5):

No break is required as `return` will be the last statement executed in the function.

Answer (score 4):

It is not "implied", but since the code will never get there, you don't have to write `break;`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just redundant, `return` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

program execution will never reach at the break statement if it has return statement before it.

Answer (score 2):

After return the program will not reach the break so you can remove the statement from there.